# How can I get and store the user ID from the URL in a Selenium test?

Tags: drupal, testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm recording Selenium tests using Selenium IDE to test the registration flow of my drupal site, which depends heavily on the rules module.

Some of the tests involve the registration of user accounts.  Since I will be using these tests on multiple servers with different amounts of users, I do not know upon starting the test which user ID to check for.  Since the user ID is in the URL, I was hoping to grab it and store it in Selenium.

Upon logging in, users are redirected to a URL like http://192.168.100.100:8888/en/user/6, where "6" is the UID.

I imagine that I could use Selenium's storeValue command to do this, but what should I put as the target to pull the user ID out of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
store | http://192.168.100.100:8888/en/user/6  | string
store | 1  | delimiter
store | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('user/')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | result
echo  | ${result}
```

Or

```
storeLocation | string
store | 1  | delimiter
store | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('user/')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | result
echo  | ${result}
```

Result will be   6

Comment: Thank you!  To get the URL, I used storeLocation instead of store.  Otherwise, I was able to get it working just as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by grabbing the url and parsing the string for the user ID if you are using RC or Selenium 2.

For specific help you'll have to shed some light on what version of Selenium you are using (IDE, Selenium RC, Selenium 2/Webdriver) and what language?

If you have a sample URL string you can get a more exact answer as well.

Comment: Thanks.  The question got moved so I've updated it appropriately.  I'm new to Selenium testing so I'm using the IDE to record tests.